# When to use atomic.LoadPointer

Tags: go, atomic

What is the difference between using `atomic.StorePointer` / `LoadPointer`:

```
data := "abc"
atomic.StorePointer(&p, unsafe.Pointer(&data))
fmt.Printf("value is %s\n", *(*string)(atomic.LoadPointer(&p)))
```

And just using using the pointer normally?

```
data := "abc"
p = unsafe.Pointer(&data)
fmt.Printf("value is %s\n", *(*string)(p))
```

What could go wrong if I decide to just read from a pointer like in the second example, instead of using `LoadPointer`? I can guess there might be some kind of race, but practically, what could actually go wrong?

Some examples:

- https://play.golang.org/p/3kfl-CB7Pk
- https://play.golang.org/p/31MlnelaJ_

Comment: Consider reading ["Benign data races: what could possibly go wrong"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) for a gentle introduction to the topic. Written by one of the core Go devs FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have one goroutine accessing the value, nothing will go wrong. As soon as you have several goroutines, you need atomic access in order to read/write the latest value (not the possibly stale value that is in your CPU cache).

Comment: In most cases, this error will be detected if you run with race-detection enabled.  In many cases where you get a data race error, it's not actually a data race condition, but rather this issue where the value cached by the compiler or CPU will be out-of-date.  (Note that the compiler is not required to reload a variable from memory if the code in a loop doesn't change it.  There is no `volatile` in go.